# Can I change the plugs on low-voltage lights to allow connection to dimmable outlets?

Tags: electrical

I have sockets around my sitting room that I can control and dim from the light switch.  I want to plug in some christmas lights but don't want to change all the plugs.  CAn i change the plug on a normal extension cable for a 5 amp small round pin plug and plug in some square pin lights to that, allowing me to dim from the light switch?

Michelle

Comment: What country are you in? It is illegal in the US and other NEC countries to place receptacles on a dimmer, unless they are specially keyed to only accept dimmable lamps.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing +

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by this that you mean UK standard 13A 3-square pin plugs and 5A 3-round pin plugs then yes.

I have done this for my lights for several years.

You do have to bear one thing in mind.  While 13A square-pin plugs contain a fuse within the plug, 5A round-pin plugs do not.  They are protected by the circuit breaker at the main fuse box.

I assume your 13A plugs actually contain a 3A or 5A fuse if you're using them just for fairy lights.  Check the ratings and where your round-pin sockets are actually protected.